# OCaml unable to load "extLib.cma" from toplevel

Tags: ocaml, utop

When I attempt to load the file `extLib.cma` in `utop`, OCaml's top level, I get the following error:

```
Cannot find file extLib.cma
```

However, if I try to install it using opam I get the following note:

```
Package extlib is already installed.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (1) How exactly do you load `extLib.cma`? (2) Do you mean to just call some of extLib's functions? Or is it something else?

Comment: try `#require "extlib";;`

Comment: After successfully using #require "extlib", I tried to use opam to install javalib and received the following error: The following dependencies couldn't be met: - javalib -> extlib <= 1.6.0

Comment: In my case, opam version 1.2.2 offers to `↘  downgrade extlib  1.7.0 to 1.5.4         [required by javalib]`

Comment: In the toplevel, use the `#list` directive to show available packages. When compiling, use the compiler invocation with `ocamlfind` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your purpose is to interactively use some of extLib's functions then

```
$ utop

μ> #require "extlib";;
μ> ExtString.String.explode "ExtLib";;
- : char list = [E; x; t; L; i; b]
```

If it's something else, then you may need to specify the exact path to `extLib.cma`, and something similar to the following should work:

```
$ utop

μ> #load "/Users/xxx/.opam/4.02.3/lib/extlib/extLib.cma";;
```

where `/Users/xxx` is your home directory/folder; `4.02.3` is my current compiler version, set via `opam switch` (IIRC, it's `system` by default).